# How to pass currently selected object in Source Control Explorer to external tool?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to add an external tool that I wrote to the context menu of source control explorer but I need to pass the currently selected object as an argument to the executable.

In Visual Studio, Tools -> External Tools...
There is an option for Arguments, I have tried most of the options in the menu accessed by clicking the arrow next to the text box. But they seem to refer to info about the tool itself, not getting information from Source Control Explorer
[image: Screenshot]

Honestly, I'm surprised I even got this far with this because the research I did was years old

I had to edit the program that I wrote which is what the tool runs because it was throwing errors because it was not getting correct input. Currently, I've had to comment out all functionality and the program now simply re-prints the arguments and waits for input.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I am not seeing the Screenshot image you added to the question, could you check if it needs to be re-added for clarifying the question?

Comment: The screenshot wasn't showing up when I initially posted the question but it seems to be now

Answer (score 0):

You can find a list of arguments for external tools here:
[Manage External Tools (MSDN)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-external-tools?view=vs-2019)

If we then use for example 
[image: External Tool dialog in Visual Studio]
$(ItemFileName) and $(ItemFileExt) - these two values are sent into our executable that which our external tool is to run (Command).

For example:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) 
        { 
           Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", args));
        }
    }
}
```

This little executable will receive the arguments from external tool as the args string array, and you can then gather up the filename selected in solution explorer.

I have tested it out in Visual Studio 2017. 
[image: External tools that is aware of selected item in solution explorer in Visual Studio]

Comment: This doesn't really tell me anything I hadn't already figured out. To put it shortly, I need to be able to pass in the currently selected object of the Source Control Explorer window. The arguments available through the GUI seem to exclusively pertain to information about the tool itself that I'm trying to add

Comment: You might consider to create a Visual Studio plugin for getting more information from Visual Studio. Using the Visual Studio SDK. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/starting-to-develop-visual-studio-extensions?view=vs-2019